# Angular - compare many old and new values

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular, is it possible to compare an old and new value when it is changed (programmatically, or otherwise)?

I guess what I'm after is functionality similar to ng-change that can be applied to any element and is triggered whenever the value in the expression is updated.

Of course, I could use $scope.$watch on the entire data model, find the individual changed values (and injecting a 'changeDirection' property) but this feels excessive.

Edit: Consider a data model of an array of 500 objects, each with 5 properties, 2 of which are integers that I need to know if they have increased/decreased.

Comment: Are you using a reference $watch, shallow $watch, or deep $watch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $watch on dot delimited paths to signify individual properties in the model you wish to watch.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input ng-model="model.name.first" />Update:{{watchVals}}
  </div>
  
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope",
      function($scope) {

        $scope.model = {
          "name": {
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Doe"
          }
        };

        $scope.val = "";
        $scope.$watch("model.name.first", function(newVal, oldVal) {
          $scope.watchVals = oldVal + " -> " + newVal;
        });
      }
    ]);
    angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was using $watch previously, but if the model was an array of 000's of objects, each with several different properties that needed to be compared - is this still the most performant method? Think a real-time financial application with red/green flashing on current prices.

Comment: Based on your comment I'd say you may be at or beyond the bounds of what Angular can handle and still be considered performant. I suggested my approach thinking that you were only interested in certain properties in the model and did not wish to watch the entire model. It might be time to consider a React-Angular hybrid approach.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend use $watch for watching object changes and you can pass new value and old value to function like this:

```
$scope.$watch('myObject', function(newValue, oldValue){
    if(!angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)){
       doSomeThing(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few key differences between `ng-change` (angular built in directive) and `$watch`.

Consider this html markup

```
<input type=text ng-model=obj.name ng-change="triggerNameChanged()">
```

1. Using ng-change would call triggerNameChanged() function only on the
   actual changes to the input by the user.However Watch are also called in
   other cases too- right when they’re being defined the first time and
   on changes made to the value not by the user, e.g. programmatically.
2. Whenever you write `{{}}` expression internally a watch is set up to look for changes in your model.
3. Using ng-change is a bit more performant, since it uses one less watch expression. Since Angular knows it should only call the expression on change events it does not need to keep evaluating it on every digest cycle, as opposed to watch.
4. By default $watch compares by reference.So If you set the third parameter to true, Angular will instead "shallow" watch the object for changes.

### **An Example of watch**

---

`$scope.$watch('myForm.modified', handler)`

in this case handler will be called if some form elements actually contains new data or if it reversed to initial state.you can use modified property of individual form elements to actually reduce amount of data sent to a server .